# Linux: mmap MAP_SHARED between regular and privileged process OK?

Tags: linux, unix, process, shared-memory, mmap

I want a process running under a restricted user to share a futex with a daemon that is basically root that drops some privileges. Does the usual shm_open and mmap etc. work with processes running as different users, and with different privileges? What specific security issues are there with this, if any (and how do I alleviate them, permissions perhaps)? Does it make a difference which of the two process creates the fd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If processes shm_open("xx",O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666); it is rw-rw-rw- and open to all. The regular umask should apply.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it uses the same as file permissions.